# Can't make input show again after typing one grocery from grocery list

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a grocery list. The goal is to type every grocery one by one, then list "Shopping is completed.", but when i write my code i can only type first grocery from list and then rest of grocery list automatically list it self to the last. What is wrong in my code?

```
listanamirnica = ["Bananas 1kg", "Bread 5x", "Milk 1l", "Apples 3kg"]
print("Things i need to buy: ",listanamirnica)

num_shoping = 0
num_items = len(listanamirnica)
print("Total number of items need to buy: ", num_items)

i_buyed = input("I buyed: ")
while num_shoping != num_items:
    if i_buyed.lower() == "bananas":
        del listanamirnica[0]
        print("Left to buy: ", listanamirnica)
        num_shoping += 1
        continue
    elif i_buyed.lower() == "bread":
        del listanamirnica[1]
        i_buyed = input("I buyed: ")
        print("Left to buy: ", listanamirnica)
        num_shoping += 1
        continue
    elif i_buyed.lower() == "milk":
        del listanamirnica[2]
        i_buyed = input("I buyed: ")
        print("Left to buy: ", listanamirnica)
        num_shoping += 1
        continue
    elif i_buyed.lower() == "apples":
        del listanamirnica[3]
        i_buyed = input("I buyed: ")
        print("Left to buy: ", listanamirnica)
        num_shoping += 1
        continue
print("You buyed all groceries.")
```

I expect after typing "bananas" to get again input "I buyed: " and then type in mlik apples bread.

Comment: `i_buyed = input("I buyed: ")` is missing in first case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues in your code, corrected below

```python
listanamirnica = ["Bananas 1kg", "Bread 5x", "Milk 1l", "Apples 3kg"]
print("Things i need to buy: ",listanamirnica)

num_shoping = 0
num_items = len(listanamirnica)
print("Total number of items need to buy: ", num_items)


while num_shoping != num_items:
    i_buyed = input("I buyed: ")
    if i_buyed.lower() == "bananas":
        listanamirnica.remove("Bananas 1kg")
        print("Left to buy: ", listanamirnica)
        num_shoping += 1
    elif i_buyed.lower() == "bread":
        listanamirnica.remove("Bread 5x")
        print("Left to buy: ", listanamirnica)
        num_shoping += 1
    elif i_buyed.lower() == "milk":
        listanamirnica.remove("Milk 1l")
        print("Left to buy: ", listanamirnica)
        num_shoping += 1
    elif i_buyed.lower() == "apples":
        listanamirnica.remove("Apples 3kg")
        print("Left to buy: ", listanamirnica)
        num_shoping += 1
print("You buyed all groceries.")
```

Changes i made:

1. Moved input inside `while` so that every iteration asks for user input
2. Removed `inputs` from your `if` cases not necessary.
3. Remove `continue` statement as its not necessary,
4. Removed `listanamirnica[0]` and added `listanamirnica.remove("Bananas 1kg")` as the index will change once you remove an item, and if you don't remove in a specified order then `0` index that you have hard-coded will delete the wrong item.

Comment: I don't want to add an answer because yours is just fine, but might be nice to explain to the OP why deleting the specific index won't work.

Also I would suggest changing `del listanamirnica[...]` to just `listanamirnica.remove("...")`

Comment: updated my answer to let you know why i removed `listanamirnica[0]`

Answer (score 0):

you just need to put the `i_buyed = input("I buyed: ")` inside the `while` loop .

and delete it from each `if/elif` , it is more clear and organized. plus you want have to write the same line over and over.  plus , since you have `elif` in the while loop , you don't need the `continue` anymore, since it will not enter other `if/elif` and just finish the iteration.

```
listanamirnica = ["Bananas 1kg", "Bread 5x", "Milk 1l", "Apples 3kg"]
print("Things i need to buy: ",listanamirnica)

num_shoping = 0
num_items = len(listanamirnica)
print("Total number of items need to buy: ", num_items)


while num_shoping != num_items:
    i_buyed = input("I buyed: ")
    if i_buyed.lower() == "bananas":
        del listanamirnica[0]
        print("Left to buy: ", listanamirnica)
        num_shoping += 1

    elif i_buyed.lower() == "bread":
        del listanamirnica[1]
        print("Left to buy: ", listanamirnica)
        num_shoping += 1

    elif i_buyed.lower() == "milk":
        del listanamirnica[2]
        print("Left to buy: ", listanamirnica)
        num_shoping += 1

    elif i_buyed.lower() == "apples":
        del listanamirnica[3]
        print("Left to buy: ", listanamirnica)
        num_shoping += 1

print("You buyed all groceries.")
```

Comment: i tried that too but when i type first etc apples it shows error.. but answer above works. Thanks anyway for looking!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems, first, as you have noticed yourself, then `input()` statement is missing in the first conditional block.
The second problem arises from the way you remove the items in you r list. the use of `del` is quite risky and you should aviode it. In particular, if you start by enterin `bread`, everything is fine, however when deleteing the item, the indices of the list shift. So `apples` will be at poition `2`. 
In order to avoide this you can take two approaches:
  1. You replace the list by a set wich is unordered but you can refer to the elements by name:

```
listanamirnica = {"Bananas 1kg", "Bread 5x", "Milk 1l", "Apples 3kg"}
...
listanamirnica.remove("Bread 5x")
```

just place the `remove` statement in each conditional block adapted accordingly.

2. If you need to keep the list update it in the following way (again for the bread part):

```
listanamirnica = [i for i in listanamirnica if i != "Bread 5x"]
```

The first approach is definetly prefereable, as in the second approach, you crreate a new list everytime

Comment: yeah, i learned now that i should avoide "del", but that's how was our "TEACHER" doing it. Thanks for comment!

Answer (score -1):

You need to move your input into the loop to get asked again

Comment: It is in the loop, bellow each `if`/`elif`

Comment: not in the first if block, which caused the problem in the first place